# Erro de instalação/Inicio de projeto com react-native

Tags: react-native, instalador

Estou tentando iniciar um projeto react-native há 2 dias no meu PC para rodar no meu dispositivo físico Android.
Ao rodar o projeto com `npx react-native run-android` aparecem os seguintes logs:

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\Pichau\Programação\Projetos\JavaScript\ControleDePagamentos-GrupoDaAgua\mobile2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\Pichau\Programação\Projetos\JavaScript\ControleDePagamentos-GrupoDaAgua\mobile2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\Pichau\Programa��o\Projetos\JavaScript\ControleDePagamentos-GrupoDaAgua\mobile2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 195

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Pichau\ProgramaÃ§Ã£o\Projetos\JavaScript\ControleDePagamentos-GrupoDaAgua\mobile2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:981:15)    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\Pichau\Programação\Projetos\JavaScript\ControleDePagamentos-GrupoDaAgua\mobile2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
```

Tentei mudar as variáveis de ambiente, mas o erro persiste. Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa, assiste o tutorial do Celke sobre como instalar o React Native, é bem explicado e funcionou comigo e com meus amigos!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3Ehi3cypDA&t=1s

Answer (score 0):

cara, muda o nome da pasta onde está localizado o projeto. A pasta "programação" tem caracteres que não são reconhecidos como o "~"; "ç".
Fiz isso no meu e funcionou.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).